# call jasper report in java code for create barcode

Tags: java, jasper-reports, barcode

I am trying to use barcode in JasperReports for which I am using barcode.jar and this  in folowing jrxml :

```
<image>
<reportElement x="265" y="44" width="100" height="50"/>
<imageExpression class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRenderable">
    <![CDATA[new com.onbarcode.barcode.jasper.JasperRenderer(
        com.onbarcode.barcode.jasper.BarcodeGenerator.draw(2, "12345", "", "X=2&Y=60"))]]>
    </imageExpression>
</image>
```

But when I call this jrxml in Java code  for use in my application i got error and no clrear error message please tell which jars I add in application  or other simple way to create barcode in jasper and then call it in Java code.

Comment: Can you please post the error or warning you can see while you try to compile/execute the report? Thanks

Comment: my ireport version is 3.0 and in ireport when i use barcode commponent i got a pdf when run jrxml file but when i use this jrxml in java code  the error " pdf document not found in session "

Comment: my ireport version is 3.0 and in ireport design mode  when i use barcode commponent  and run jrxml file i have a pdf with barcode but when i use this jrxml in java code the error " pdf document not found in session " and when i delete the barcode element from ireport i get no error and pdf show items in java code

Comment: please can you send a sample java application  that print barcode from jasper in java application?